Does a Starlit Span Magus get the increased dice size for Ignition
A starlit span can Spell Strike at range:

When you use Spellstrike, you can make a ranged weapon or ranged unarmed Strike, as long as the target is within the first range increment of your ranged weapon or ranged unarmed attack. You can deliver the spell even if its range is shorter than the range increment of your ranged attack.

The spell Ignition does more damage when cast in melee range:

If the target is within your melee reach, you can choose to make a melee spell attack with the flame instead of a ranged spell attack, which increases all the spell's damage dice to d6s.

Can you get the increased ignition damage with a Starlit Span magus's ranged spell strike?

No
When you cast/spellstrike with ignition, the default damage is

Make a spell attack roll against the target's AC, dealing 2d4 fire damage on a hit.

It has an additional caveat;

If the target is within your melee reach,

The target is not in your melee reach, so you do not qualify to make use of the caveat. Nothing about Spell Strike being able to "deliver the spell even if its range is shorter" extends your melee reach.

Just to check - not that it'd make for a good build but a Starlit Span with a Lancer/Wrecker shooting a target 10 feet away COULD apply the increased damage die, right, since the target would also be within their melee reach? Since these are combination weapons with Reach?

That one's a bit harder and should probably be its own question. My initial answer would be that it depends on which setting the weapon is in. Flail/Spear - yes; Sling/Bow - no. I left out the rest of the text from ignition that wasn't applicable to this question, but "If the target is within your melee reach, you can choose to make a melee spell attack with the flame instead of a ranged spell attack". Starlit Span can make either melee or ranged Spellstrikes, but I'm not sure if you could make a melee-reach ranged attack that qualifies. Regardless, you would need to be adjacent...

to the target because you don't have Reach while in Ranged mode. (You're not in both, you have to use an action to switch between the modes)

I'd say yes, personally. If you can't use the melee version of Ignition with a ranged Spellstrike because the enemies aren't in melee, then it should also mean that you can't use melee-only spells, like Gouging Claw, with a ranged Spellstrike, either. But, that's not the case. The projectile is considered to be where the spell originates, so you absolutely should be able to use the melee version of Ignition if you hit the target with the projectile. Also, it doesn't make sense that Ignition is the one spell every other form of Magus except Starlit Span can use to it's full effect, when Starlit Span can use literally every other spell equally well as the other Magus types.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
